# how to write php variable inside a javascript code

Tags: php, javascript

this is the path i'm using in an img src attribute which i'm using in a php program

```
'user/hangout_images/".$imag_addr." '
```

can anybody tell how to insert the path given above into the path given in the following javascript code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imageid').attr( "src", "/new/path/to/image.jpg" );
});
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you told us what files each section of code was in.  Are they in the same file, or is the javascript file being included in the header (or somewhere else?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to put your javascript in with you php I believe you have to use AJAX.
This *might* work..

source.php

```
$image_addr = "/blah/blah/blah.jpg"
echo $image_addr;
```

stuff.html (or .js)

```
    $.get('source.php', setimg);

function setimg(data) {
       $('#imageid').attr( "src", data );
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imageid').attr( "src", '<?php echo "user/hangout_images/$imag_addr"; ?>' );
});
```

Comment: @harsh This would only work when the javascript it within the php file. If the javascript is in a .js file, it won't work (unless your server processes .js files as php).

Comment: @Neal: you have to surround the php code with quotes; `"<?php ... ?>"`

Comment: @M42, there is no reason to do that

Comment: @Neal: but you've just modified your answser this way while I submit my comment.

Answer (score 4):

You should try to keep as much HTML out of the PHP as possible like this, hopefully I'm not being to nitpicky...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imageid').attr( "src", "/new/path/to/<?php echo $image_addr;?>" );
});
```

Also remember that PHP renders on the server before javascript (which renders in the browser), so if you are trying to make a PHP change to a page that is already loaded, that won't work.